# jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.2 migration causes: javax.faces.FacesException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working on a project about migrating from jsf1.2 to JSF 2.2,I already removed the jsf 1.2 jars and I replaced them by jsf 2.2 jars! But when I'm trying to change schema namespace in faces-config file(new namespace definition for jsf 2.2) I got this exeception:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is 
not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
```

Comment: paste faces-config.xml file content

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an inconsistence in your dependencies.
This Exception obviously points out, that

```
org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider
```

is not an extension of

```
com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
```

However, I've done a little research using http://grepcode.com to get a better Picture of this Problem.
It seams, that `JandexAnnotationProvider` actualy **is** an extension of `AnnotationProvider`, at least after jboss-as-web version 7.0.0

Also Interesting was, that `JandexAnnotationProvider` disappeared after version 7.1.2.Final

I would suggest updating to the latest Version of jboss-as-web, which is 7.2.0
This class might got replaced for a reason related to your problem.

You can acquire this version at:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-web/7.2.0.Final/jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar

or as Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-web</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Best regards,

J.Adam